# How Do I Create an Application For Ingenico 5100

Tags: point-of-sale

i want to build application for ingenico 5100. It must download data from the link and print it. for example http://domain.com/data.txt or http://domain.com/data.xml this operation should be done at regular intervals. I created application for windowsCE but ingenico OS's diffrent. Can you help me this subject. I just want your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You need Ingedev(Ingenico SDK) to develop application on i5100 etc.
You can get this SDK from Ingenico.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't have ingenico sdk. Ingenico said that we can't give sdk for i5100.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use RxTx (java lib) to implement Concert protocol via serial port.